# List slicing vs copying

Tags: python

Does python `copy` act the same as doing `L[:]` or does `L[:]` act more like `deepcopy` or something else? Just a basic example would be:

```
from copy import copy
L = [1,2,3]
L[:]
# [1,2,3]
copy(L)
# [1,2,3]
```

Comment: That's not a very useful example, because integers are immutable - you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between a deep and shallow copy anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`L.copy()` and `L[:]` work identically - both are shallow copies. At first only `L[:]` existed; `.copy()` was added later so that generic code needing a copy could spell it in a unform way (`dict.copy()`, `set.copy()`, ...).

### Examples

```py
>>> L = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> L1 = L[:]
>>> [a is b for a, b in zip(L, L1)]
[True, True]
>>> L1 = L.copy()
>>> [a is b for a, b in zip(L, L1)]
[True, True]
>>> import copy
>>> L1 = copy.copy(L)
>>> [a is b for a, b in zip(L, L1)]
[True, True]
>>> L1 = copy.deepcopy(L) # this one differs!
>>> [a is b for a, b in zip(L, L1)]
[False, False]
```

Comment: thanks, for thoroughness want to just add a brief example of how `[:]`/`copy` is different than `deepcopy` ?

Comment: Sure - added examples of 4 ways of copying.

Answer (score 1):

Its complicated. Objects decide for themselves what slicing means. `L[1:3]` is turned into a call to a magic method `L.__getitem__(slice(1,3))` and the object decides what it should do with that. `list` will make a shallow copy.

Other objects will do different things. A range object for example, gives you a new range object.

```
>>> range(5)[:3]
range(0, 3)
```

slicing in packages that do a lot of meta programming and get more complicated still.

Comment: All true enough, but the question title specifically asked only about "list slicing vs copying".

Answer (score 1):

To add onto Tim Peters' answer. From the `copy` module documentation:

> Shallow copies of dictionaries can be made using `dict.copy()`, and of lists by assigning a slice of the entire list, for example, `copied_list = original_list[:]`.

Also, to address the comment below Tim Peters' answer, with regards to what is different between `copy` and `deepcopy`:

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):

> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

For instance look at the following:

```
>>> import copy
>>> l1 = [[1,2], 2, 3]
>>> l2 = copy.copy(l1)
>>> l1[0].append(3)
>>> l1
[[1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
>>> l2
[[1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
>>> l3 = copy.deepcopy(l1)
>>> l1[0].append(4)
>>> l1
[[1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 3]
>>> l3
[[1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
```

When `l2` is copied with (shallow)`copy`, the reference for the first entry is shared between `l1` and `l2`. So, mutating `l1[0]` will also mutate `l2[0]`. But in the `deepcopy` (`l3`), the copying is done recursively, so `l1[0] != l3[0]` and mutating one does not influence the other.